# How to prevent assigning object to class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am  wondering how to prevent this from happening?

```js
@jsonReflect()
class TestClass {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    @jsonIgnore()
    address?: string;
}
const test = { name : "John", age: 10 };
```

The problem is, creation of object `{ name : "John", age: 10 }` strips object of class decorators, constructor logic etc.
How can I explicitly prevent this behaviour?

There is another deserialization problem when it comes to objects like these `{ name : "John", age: 10 }`. Sometimes, I have classes like this:

```js
export class ConnectorSignature {
    name!: string;
    dataType!: string;
    @jsonIgnore()
    dataReference!: number;
}
```

Classes like these have to be deserialized through `JSON.parse("some string")` but after deserialization they also come out as 'objects from scratch'. So, any decorators are gone, any constructor logic is gone and meta is gone really. E.g.

```js
// this will look like ConnectorSignature class, but...
const connectorData: ConnectorSignature = JSON.parse("some string");

// serializing it back will ignore decorator
console.log(JSON.stringify(connectorData));
/* and produce all fields: 
'{
  "name": "Blue",
  "dataType": "Integer",
  "dataReference": 2,
}'
*/
```

Comment: that isn't stripping - that just happens to be an object that matches the _interface_ of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add any private member to your class:

```
class TestClass {
    private isClass = true
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    address?: string;
}

const test1: TestClass = { name : "John", age: 10 }; // error
const test2: TestClass = { name : "John", age: 10, isClass: true }; // error
const test3: TestClass = new TestClass() // fine
```

Now it's not possible for a simple object to conform to that interface at all.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QAcAnASwDcwl5oSI1IYBeaJIgV3l3wDswBbeAH4AXNGSluAcwDcXPGElDR3NnwBG8IrPzQwAEz1FEEEWNYkpsgL7ZswAPbdkLREgCMohMnoZmmaLwC0KIARABS9gAW3CEANLqKom4ADNBW0tAA9JnQmkT2RHaOzlTIAEyerj5MWAH81KER0XEJ8EnJ8bTVoqwcaRnZuUT5hQ5OSC7IAMyV3ug13PAA7nBV8wAUAJRZOQBmFpxAA)